How do I get cromwell to use GCP "n" machines, not "e" ones
Moving a Cromwell WDL workflow to GCP.  Cromwell appears to really love using the "e" (for "efficiency", i.e. slow and worthless) machine types.  I had a task of "extract 6 ~10gb compressed files, then process them", that I ran on both "e2-highcpu-8" and "n2-standard-8" machines.
The n2-standard-8 took an hour and a half.  The e2-highcpu-8 took three and a half hours.
Given that we're paying for the 700GiB of disk space in addition to the machine, it's a clear loss using the "e" machine.
Is it documented any place how to tell cromwell gcp batch which machine "family" to use?

What is WDL and GCP? Can you provide any more additional context around your question (e.g. links about the programs or documentation)?
